# How to construct a path between two points in a general $n-surface$?

Tags: differential-geometry, path-connected

Hope this isn't a duplicate.

Let $S$ be an n-surface. Now since for any finite dimensional Topological space, connectedness and path-connectedness are equivalent notions, to show an n-surface to be path-connected we can proceed to show that it's connected and to show connectedness there are lots of tools. It tells that given any two points in $S$, $\exists$ a path joining those two points lying entirely within $S$.

But currently I'm trying to construct an explicit path between two points in $S$ . So all we have are arbitrary two points $x$ , $y$ $\in S$ and an equation of the form , say, $f(x_1 ,x_2,\ldots ,x_{n+1}) = c$ for some $f : {\Bbb R}^{n+1} \to \Bbb R$ , $f$ is smooth , $c \in \Bbb R$ is a regular value of $f$ (i.e. $f(x_1 ,x_2,\ldots ,x_{n+1}) = c$ is a level set) .

So, firstly I was looking to construct it for some relatively familiar surfaces like Annulus and then to chalk out a strategy for a general n-surface. But I can't figure out anything!

If someone can help by first giving an explicit path in a particular surface and then share some ideas on how to construct one such for a general n-surface , it will be extremely helpful .

Comment: Do you have any regularity requirements on the curve? I know you wanted an explicit construction, but the easiest way to prove this is to show connected + locally path-connected implies path-connected (see, for example, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878410/connected-and-locally-path-connected). It is easy to see $n$-surfaces are locally path connected (they are locally Euclidean, after all).

Comment: It is just too vague. If $f$ is arbitraray, no one can tell how to find those paths. Indeed the level set might not even be connected, or $n$-dimensional.

Comment: @Glare Yes I need an explicit path.

Comment: @JohnMa At least one can share some idea on how to proceed, if not the entire path.

Comment: I mean, there is no general way to proceed. After all, any closed set in $\mathbb R^n$ is a level set of some smooth function $f$. How can you find a path in any arbitrary closed sets?

Comment: @JohnMa while what you say is true, ThatIs actually means "regular hypersurface" here, but the point still stands. ThatIs, reading your post again it seems you want to prove connectedness by proving path connectedness, but as you already pointed out these are equivalent notions for regular hypersurfaces. You need to assume one to prove the other. As an example to show a generic construction is doomed, consider $f(x) = x^2$; then $\{\pm 1\} = \{x: f(x)=1\}$ is a regular $0$-dimensional hypersurface, but is not connected. You can do similar constructions for higher dimensions.

Comment: @Glare frankly speaking, I've seen some question papers asking to come up with some explicit construction of paths and while solving them I was stuck. So I was wondering if someone could give me some idea, then I could try to solve the problems, otherwise I would have to leave the questions in the exam and there will not be any chance of me cracking the exam!

Comment: @ThatIs Ahhh, that makes a lot more sense. So you essentially want tips? I'm not sure what kinds of problems you're looking at, but I most commonly see these questions in the context of matrix of Lie groups (so ${\textrm GL}_+(n,{\mathbb R}), {\rm SO}(n), {\rm U}(n), {\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb C})$, etc.) Almost all of these rely on diagonalization arguments. Maybe you could edit your post to include some examples of the problems you're working on?